# Testing hibernate Model/DAO classes

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, testing

I am currently working on a project with a rather complex data model, a lot of relationships, optional, mandatory etc.
We want to test our models and daos, but we are weary of writing all the tests manually. The biggest problem actually is filling the model objects to be tested with sample data. For a simple model this is easy, sure, but the problem comes in when you have a lot of mandatory relationships and thus need to setup a big object graph for each test.

Does any one know any tools or frameworks that simplify testing hibernate models/dao's?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but as I saw that in dbUnit you have to create a data set. This task is not a simple one in my case, as I have a very complex data model.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://code.google.com/p/template4/. It allows generating hibernate data using patterns.

Comment: It sounds like a promising project. Unfortunately the project isn't very active: the last commits are over 1 year ago.

Answer (score 0):

I have always created the data in the DB first using SQL scripts rather than creating the data programmatically using Hibernate.  The SQL file contains just a bunch of insert statement that get executed against an embedded DB. Using the H2 db, my driver URL is the following:

jdbc:h2:mem:;MODE=Oracle;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'test/conf/createDb.sql'

This automagically creates a new DB and populates the db with test data against which I write me dao test cases.